# Android socket programming with ProgressDialog in a method

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, progressdialog

I would like to have a method that sends a udp broadcast and returns the responses in a list. In addition, a progress dialog is displayed during the broadcast and cancels when the method returns.

I have successfully accomplished the same thing with AsyncTask, but when I do that the class becomes very difficult to reuse because I have to do different things in the onPostExecute depending on where I start the AsyncTask. This is why I would much rather do it with a Thread, below is my method so far:

```
public static ArrayList<Device> broadcastForDevices(final String broadcastMessage,Context context){
        final ProgressDialog p=ProgressDialog.show(context, null,"Broadcasting...",false);

        final Handler handler= new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                 Log.i(TAG,"Dismissing");
                 p.dismiss();
            }
        };
        Thread broadcastForDevices=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    DatagramSocket udpBroadcastSocket=null;
                    try{
                        udpBroadcastSocket= new DatagramSocket();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Created datagram socket");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Log.i(TAG,"Exception "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                    detectedDevices=processDeviceResponses(sendBroadcastPackets(udpBroadcastSocket,broadcastMessage));
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
        });
        //Start then join normally defeats purpose of thread, but socket programming must be done off the UI thread
        broadcastForDevices.start();
        try {
            broadcastForDevices.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Interrupted exception");
        }
        return detectedDevices;
    }
```

The problem with above code is that the progress dialog never shows up. If I make the progress dialog a member variable of the class instead of final, the progress dialog shows up but is never cancelled. In both cases, the "Dismissing" gets logged somehow. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: I think you should check the message what you getting in handler. If the message is true then dismiss progress dialog.

Comment: @Vid not sure what that would accomplish ? I would like to dismiss the dialog at the end of the run method

Comment: Does it show after the thread ended if you remove `handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);` ?

Comment: @greenapps yes is does show in that case

Comment: @greenapps but it is not creating and dismissing it so fast I can't see it (I tried putting a thread.sleep(3000) inside the socket thread and it still doesn't show)

Comment: The `Thread.join()` is preventing the ProgressDialogfrom showing until the thread ends. You did not show the whole function which ends with `return detectedDevices;`. Please do. And show how you call it.

Comment: `If I make the progress dialog a member variable of the class instead of final, the progress dialog shows up but is never cancelled`  ?? Please post that code in a separate code block and we will have look. Sorry i did not grab that before. Wich class?

Answer (score 0):

Using Thread:join() will not solve anything. The things you first did in onPostExecute you could now do in your Handler.

Comment: If I do them in the handler, the function will return before the handler gets called. Again I would like the function to return once the thread is complete, hence the .join().

Comment: Yes indeed. So your design is wrong. That function should not return anything. Instead place the code you would do with the result in the handler. Just as you had in onPostExecute.

Comment: The function works fine without the addition of the progress dialog. My question was, is there any way to display a progress dialog while the thread was performing the broadcast and then dismiss when it is done (all within the function). So I gather that what you mean is this is not possible ?

Comment: You said the code in onPostExecute became to complicated as you called the AsyncTask for more purposes. It does not matter if you use an AsyncTask or Thread. Give both a Callback parameter wenn you call them. Then inOnPostExecute or in handler call the callback function.

Comment: Yeah I did think about passing a callback into async task's onPostExecute, not really sure how to do that in Java, is there something like a function pointer in Java I could use?

Comment: Use `Callback` class.